# Not able to perform token/secret pair authentication. It has been deprecated by git

Tags: webdrivermanager-java

Not able to perform token/secret pair authentication any more since git have deprecated the same. PFB for reference,

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#oauth2-keysecret

plz let me know the workaround for the authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WebDriverManager 5, you simply need to specify a GitHub token (and not the token/secret anymore). Take a look to the [documentation](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/).